# Xpath. How to select all text between two tags?

Tags: python, xpath

Here is the HTML source code

```
<div class="text">
 <a name="dst100030"></a>
 <pre id="p73" class="P">
 <span class="blk">│Лабораторные методы исследования                                         │</span>
 </pre>
 <pre id="p74" class="P">
 <span class="blk">├────────────┬───────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────────┤</span></pre>
 <a name="dst100031"></a>
```

I need to get all text in between the two `<a name="dst100030">` tags. Here's what I tried:

```
response.xpath('//pre//text()[preceding-sibling::a[@name="dst100030"] and following-sibling::a[@name="dst100031"]]')
```

But it returns empty list. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you set on using xpath? Or would you be open to using modules like re? to accomplish your task.

Comment: @Chris  I am open to any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a>` is a sibling of `<pre>`, not the text(). You can use `preceding::a` instead (and similarly for `following`).

Comment: Thanks.what if there is a list of such blocks and i need to get text from in between  each of them. Any solution for such? 
<a name="dst100030"></a>'>
<a name="dst100031"></a>'>
<a name="dst100032"></a>'>
<a name="dst100033"></a>'>
<a name="dst100034"></a>'>
<a name="dst100035"></a>'>
<a name="dst100036"></a>'>
<a name="dst100037"></a>'>

Comment: To ask a new question, create a new question.

Comment: please check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564776/get-all-xpath-intersection-of-two-sets-on-the-page

Answer (score -2):

A solution to what you have asked using re:

**Note:** As others have mentioned in the comments this may not be the best solution - you are better to use a proper parser.

```
import re

source_code ='<div class="text"><a name="dst100030"></a><pre id="p73" class="P"><span class="blk">│Лабораторные методы исследования│</span></pre><pre id="p74" class="P"><span class="blk">├────────────┬───────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────────┤</span></pre></a name="dst100031"></a>'
text = re.findall('<a name="dst100030">(.*)</a name="dst100031">', source_code)
print(text)
```

Comment: Never parse XML with regex.  Use a real XML parser.  No, it doesn't matter that OP said "I am open to any solution."

Comment: He said he was open to any solution - this works, even if it may not be the best solution.

Comment: @Chris, ...however, StackOverflow is a teaching resource. It's irresponsible to teach a technique if you wouldn't be willing to maintain code that used it (to provide technical support to clients/customers who are using that technique, etc). This may "work" with the *very specific* input given, but it's fragile: Other HTML with the exact same semantics but different formatting would fail.

Comment: Speaking as someone who's had to deal with support tickets from customers whose hand-rolled parsers broke when we changed newlines / added additional fields / made other changes that a properly-designed parser would ignore, it matters.

Comment: One of an infinite number of examples of what could go wrong:  A second space between `div` and `class` would be perfectly well-formed yet would break your regex solution.  And don't try to fix that because there're many more.   See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/290085 and many other resources explaining why.

Comment: Or we could be in XHTML with `xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` -- a real parser would know that a `h:div` is still a div. A regex won't. And then there are comments, CDATA sections, etc, etc, etc.